# Alternative to adjustwidth for use with a lettrine (or alternative to lettrine)

Tags: indentation, lettrine

I'm using `\lettrine` for the first paragraph of a section. However I'd like that section to be narrower than the others so I'm also using `adjustwidth` from the `changepage` package. This causes alignment problem for the next paragraphs of that section

If I use this:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{1.5cm}{1.5cm}
\lettrine[lines=3]{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.

Lorem ipsum (paragraph 2) dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.
\end{adjustwidth}
```

Then the second paragraph has a blank space on the left that looks as if it were expecting the `L` lettrine to be there (in other words, its `\parshape` is wrong). This is expected results since `adjustwidth` uses list and that `lettrine` doesn't work well with list (according to its documentation).

However, if I do:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{1.5cm}{1.5cm}
\lettrine[lines=3]{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.
\end{adjustwidth}
\begin{adjustwidth}{1.5cm}{1.5cm}
Lorem ipsum (paragraph 2) dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.
\end{adjustwidth}
```

Then everything works fine. However it's not very practical because I will have to do it in several places.

Is there any known elegant solution/package/newenvironment for this problem. i.e. a replacement to `adjustwidth` that would work with `lettrine` ? Or alternatively a replacement to `lettrine` that would work with `adjustwidth` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have lists in the narrower paragraphs, then this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lettrine,lipsum,lmodern}

\newenvironment{narrow}
  {\par\leftskip=1.5cm \rightskip=\leftskip}
  {\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{narrow}
\lettrine[lines=3]{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.

Lorem ipsum (paragraph 2) dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.
\end{narrow}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. I've refined it into:
    `\newenvironment{narrow}[1][1.5cm]
      {\par\leftskip=#1 \rightskip=\leftskip}
      {\par}`