# Are Lettrines Incompatible with the Adjustwidth Environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lettrine, horizontal, adjustwidth, changepage

Consider the following code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}   
\usepackage{changepage} % for adjustwidth environment
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\noindent \lipsum[1]
\vskip 10pt
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{}
\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth}

\vskip 10pt

\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{}
\lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\color{red}{\textbf{L}}}{orem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

It produces the output:

[image]

As you can see, `\adjustwidth` does what it's supposed to do when a lettrine is not involved. However, when `\adjustwidth` is applied to the paragraph with a lettrine, two differences result:
(1) The paragraph is not (in this case) shifted 1cm to the right; and (2) the length of the paragraph is not the same length as the first (unadjusted) paragraph; but rather, appears to be pretty much assuming the length of the second paragraph as if it had been shifted.

QUESTION: Can anyone explain why these two phenomena are occurring; and how may I get `\adjustbox` (or something else) work for a paragraph containing a lettrine?

Thank you.

**UPDATE** I have found this post, which previously I was unaware of:  [Alternative to adjustwidth for use with a lettrine (or alternative to lettrine)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66332/alternative-to-adjustwidth-for-use-with-a-lettrine-or-alternative-to-lettrine?rq=1). In it, egreg offers an alternative to `adjustwidth` --- so, I don't know if this question should be closed as a duplicate, or whether it should be left open in the hope that someone may offer an `adjustwidth` ``fix''. Bernard says that his current installation does not have the problem I have described. In any case. egreg does offer a nice alternative.

Comment: With an up-to-date installation, I have no problem.

Comment: @Bernard That's good to know. It sounds like the problem may have been fixed along the way. Perhaps someone knows if it was a bug and if and when there was a revision to the `changepage` package.

Comment: I can confirm @Bernard's result.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes I just added an update posting egreg's  alternative solution which I found. Perhaps I should delete the question? I have suggested that it may be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes I have just voted to close the question as a duplicate.